# Android; If else statement not working

Tags: java, android

I am working with android. I am creating a mobile application that need to give a suggestion on calories intake for type-1 diabetic based on body mass index, age and physical activity. My problem is my if else statement is not working. The if else coding is at Review.java and I need to display the output at Result.java.

Bmi.java

```
final Context context = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bmi);

    // Find UI elements by ID and save to variable
    final EditText height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height_input);
    final EditText weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight_input);
    final TextView bmi_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bmi_result);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bmi_calc_button);
    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NavigateButton);

    // Listen for our click event
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //String bmi = bmi_result.getText().toString();

            // Check for null
            if (height.getText().toString().length() < 1) {
                sendToast("You must enter your height!");
                // Abort the onClick if null
                return;
            }
            if (weight.getText().toString().length() < 1) {
                sendToast("You must enter your weight, sorry!");
                // Abort the onClick if null
                return;
            }
            // Passed the null checks, let's do some math!

            /***
             * Android is funny this way, but you have
             * to convert it back and forth from integer/float
             * to strings, you'll get used to it. ;)
             */
            // Convert height from string to float
            float h = Float.valueOf(height.getText().toString());
            float w = Float.valueOf(weight.getText().toString());

            /***
             * Time for math!
             * BMI is calculated
             * (weigth in kg / (height in meter * height in meter)
             * But since we want the user to input in CM, we just
             * multiply it with 10 000 to get the correct value.
             */
            float BMI = w / (h * h) * 10000;

            // Set the bmi_result view item of the value of our BMI
            bmi_result.setText(String.valueOf(BMI));

            String textBMI = bmi_result.getText().toString();
        }
    });

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            String textBMI = bmi_result.getText().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Bmi.this, Age.class);
            intent.putExtra("Ans_bmi",textBMI);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
}
```

Age.java

```
private RadioGroup age;
//private RadioButton radioAgeButton;
private Button b;
public String selectedType= "";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.age);

    age = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    final RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb1);
    final RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb2);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    age.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if (checkedId == R.id.rb1) {
                selectedType = rb1.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(Age.this, "Your age is around 41 - 45", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
                else if (checkedId == R.id.rb2) {
                selectedType = rb2.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(Age.this, "Your age is around 46 - 50", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }//int selectedId = age.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            //radioAgeButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
            //Toast.makeText(Age.this, radioAgeButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String textBMI = intent.getStringExtra("Ans_bmi");

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Age.this, Physical_Activity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            bundle.putString("Ans_bmi", textBMI);
            bundle.putString("Ans_age", selectedType);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Physical_Activity.java

```
private RadioGroup activity;
//private RadioButton radioActivityButton;
private String selectedType = "";
private Button b;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.physical_activity);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String textBMI = intent.getStringExtra("Ans_bmi");
    final String umur = intent.getStringExtra("Ans_age");

    final TextView cf_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_result);

    activity = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    final RadioButton rbs = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbsedentary);
    final RadioButton rbm = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbmoderate);
    final RadioButton rba = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rbactive);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    activity.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if (checkedId == R.id.rbsedentary) {
                selectedType = rbs.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(Physical_Activity.this, "Your physical activity is Sedentary Active", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (checkedId == R.id.rbmoderate) {
                selectedType = rbm.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(Physical_Activity.this, "Your physical activity is Moderately Active", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (checkedId == R.id.rbactive) {
                selectedType = rba.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(Physical_Activity.this, "Your physical activity is Active", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            //int selectedId = activity.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            //radioActivityButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);
            //Toast.makeText(Physical_Activity.this, radioActivityButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Physical_Activity.this, Review.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            bundle.putString("Ans_bmi", textBMI);
            bundle.putString("Ans_age", umur);
            bundle.putString("Ans_phy", selectedType);
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Review.java

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.review);

    //Create a bundle object to store the bundle added to the intent
    final Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    //Get the values out by key
    final String textBMI = bundle.getString("Ans_bmi");
    final String umur = bundle.getString("Ans_age");
    final String aktiviti = bundle.getString("Ans_phy");

    final String txtcf = bundle.getString("cfDisease");

    //Get the textview controls
    final TextView txtage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    final TextView txtphy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    final TextView txtbmi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);

    final TextView cf_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);

    //Button buttonSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsend);

    //Set the text values of the text controls
    txtage.setText(textBMI);
    txtphy.setText(umur);
    txtbmi.setText(aktiviti);
    cf_result.setText(txtcf);

    Button submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsend);


    final Intent intentsubmit = new Intent();

    intentsubmit.setClass(Review.this, Result.class);
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(intentsubmit);

            String calories;

            if (txtage.toString().equals(context.getString(R.string.age1)))
            {
                if (txtphy.toString().equals(context.getString(R.string.moderate)))
                {
                    calories = "1800 cal";

                    cf_result.setText(String.valueOf(calories));
                    String txtcf = cf_result.getText().toString();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Review.this, Result.class);
                    intentsubmit.setClass(Review.this, Result.class);
                    intentsubmit.putExtra("cfDisease", txtcf);
                    startActivity(intentsubmit);
                }
            }
            else if (txtage.toString().equals(context.getString(R.string.age2)))
            {
                if (txtphy.toString().equals(context.getString(R.string.active)))
                {
                    calories = "2000 cal";

                    cf_result.setText(String.valueOf(calories));

                    String txtcf = cf_result.getText().toString();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Review.this, Result.class);
                    intentsubmit.setClass(Review.this, Result.class);
                    intentsubmit.putExtra("cfDisease", txtcf);
                    startActivity(intentsubmit);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Result.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.result);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String txtcf = intent.getStringExtra("cfDisease");

    final TextView keputusan = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.show_result);

    keputusan.setText(txtcf);
}
```

Comment: `My problem is my output is not working.` what do you mean by that?

Comment: My output will be the "calories". But the output did not appear

Comment: What output did you get?  Please explain what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you're checking that `bundle.getString("Ans_bmi") == R.string.age1`  AND 
`bundle.getString("Ans_age") == R.string.moderate`

-- or --

`bundle.getString("Ans_bmi") == R.string.age2`  AND 
`bundle.getString("Ans_age") == R.string.active`

If neither of these sets of conditions are true, your code won't succeed. I think your mistake is at Review.java:

```
//Get the values out by key
final String textBMI = bundle.getString("Ans_bmi");
final String umur = bundle.getString("Ans_age");
final String aktiviti = bundle.getString("Ans_phy");
```

and

```
//Set the text values of the text controls
txtage.setText(textBMI);
txtphy.setText(umur);
txtbmi.setText(aktiviti);
```

**My Solution**

Look where you are putting the strings. I re-arranged the variables and changed the names to make more sense:

```
//Get the values out by key
final String textBMI = bundle.getString("Ans_bmi");
final String textAge = bundle.getString("Ans_age");
final String textPhy = bundle.getString("Ans_phy");
```

and

```
//Set the text values of the text controls
txtage.setText(textAge);
txtphy.setText(textPhy);
txtbmi.setText(textBMI);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works :) @mmarkman